# JWT token decode in cakephp

Tags: php, api, cakephp, jwt

I am facing a problem to decode token (JWT). Here it's encoded successfully and it provides me with a token. My code code is:

```
$tokenData = $this->set([
                'data' => [
                    'token' => JWT::encode([
                        'sub' => $user['username'],
                        'exp' =>  time() + 202200
                    ],

                        Security::salt())
                ],
                '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
            ]);
```

It returns `"token":{"token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}`

To decode this I used:

```
$JWT_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$token = JWT::decode($JWT_KEY);
dd($token);
```

How can I get it? specially time. Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you get what? What does the `dd` show you?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using firebase JWT take a look to: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

for me that command worked, here's a piece of my code:

$jwt= $this->request->data['_token'];
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $this->pepper, array('HS256'));

//$decoded is an object with your token decoded data